# Postgresql import dump with pgadmin3

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin

i have been trying to import a Postgresql dump with my pgadmin3 interface but im running into problems. These dump was generated with `pg_dump dbname > dump_file.sql`

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1903: \.
           ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 45693
```

the code:

```
--
-- Data for Name: auth_group; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

COPY auth_group (id, name) FROM stdin;
\.
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PgAdmin-III's SQL window unfortunately does not understand `psql` backslash commands, `COPY ... FROM STDIN`, etc.

You must restore with `psql`.

```
 psql -f dump_file.sql
```

Comment: whats the difference with `psql dbname < dump_file.sql` ?